# Power transistor identification: old RCA

Tags: transistors, identification, rca

Looking for an alternative/substitution for an old RCA power transistor:

[image]

Google and old RCA catalogues did not provide any useful information.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The target circuit is needed. There may be something about the target circuit that is peculiar to this transistor and therefore trying to locate an alternative based on no linked data sheet and a prayer is asking for trouble.

Comment: I have lots of old xref books, including one from RCA specifically, but none of them have that particular number. This probably means that it is some manufacturer's internal part number. I think you're going to have to reverse-engineer the requirements for the device from the specific circuit that it's in and pick a replacement based on that.

Comment: It comes form an old German power supply Gossen Konstanter 44 T 20 R 10  (20V 10A)
I already asked the company about the circuit diagram and still waiting for the reply

A comparable power supply from this company (34K 32 R4) has 2N3055 transistors. So if I do not find any other clue I will try them. 

Thank you very much for the help

Comment: Looks like an OEM part number. My RCA transistor has a Tek part number as well,  so I guess it was common to relabel them back in the days. I hope you can get a schematic...

Comment: Asking us to recommend an alternative is off-topic here, but you can ask to identify the component so that you can look for a suitable alternative.

Answer (score 1):

if more than one such transistor is used, then disconnect one that works and measure it.

The BETA may have been selected to be higher, or for matching.

The breakdown voltage may be been tested, and a HIGHER Breakdown voltage transistor selected, because sustained high voltage was part of the operating conditions.

Or faster switching devices were chosen, for higher efficiency.